# Complex square matrices, proving there exists x,y in C^n such that A=xy*

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

Suppose A $\in$ $M_{nxn}$ the set of complex square matrices.  Show the following statements are equivalent

a) A has rank 1

b) $\exists$x,y $\in$ $C^n$ such that $A=xy^*$

What are the right and left eigenvectors of A and the corresponding eigenvalues?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about this problem? Since you're asked to prove an equivalence, you have $\rm a\Rightarrow b$ and $\rm b\Rightarrow a$ to prove. Do you have any inroads in either of those two directions?

Comment: you have been posting so many homework type questions here. how many problems do you do on your own? you will learn a lot more linear algebra if you take the time to do some problems on your own.

Comment: I multiplied out what it would look like - the product of $xy^*$, and I'm getting an nxn complex matrix as the result.  Now I'm trying to see what assuming a) A has rank 1 should tell me about b).  My first thoughts would be perhaps this is a question about normal matrices, which satisfy $AA^*$ = $A^*A$.  But for now, I don't see how A having rank 1 is of any help in implying part b)...

Comment: what does it mean for a matrix to be of rank one?

Comment: none of what I have posted are homework questions, @abel.  there are actually old prelim questions for my school.  i'm taking the exams in less than two weeks, so i would like to see as many problems and discuss as many solutions as possible until my exam dates Jan 7th, 8th, and 9th.  re: linear algebra, i've gone nearly cover to cover with two textbooks :)  these questions are a bit different from ones i work on from textbooks and in homework assignments for my full year sequence of linear algebra at school...so i'd love to see more diverse perspectives on solving these problems, if possible

Comment: rank one implies that the matrix has at most one linearly independent column and one linearly independent row (since row rank = column rank) ... hmmm...not sure how it would help, though...

Comment: ^If $A$ has only one linearly independent column, then the column space is $\text{span}\{v\}$ for some non-zero vector $v$, and then each column is a scalar multiple of this vector $v$. Do you see how this helps?

Comment: going cover to cover means what? you got to do problems; tone of them. of course you start with some simple computational problems. when you run into technical terms like rank one matrix look it up. look up rank one matrix in the index of your text book. without knowing every technical word in a question you will have hard time successfully solving problems. i teach linear algebra.

Comment: Hint: as $A$ has only one independent column, let such a column be $\bf x$.  What does this tell you about the other columns of $A$?

Comment: good luck on your prelim exams.

Comment: thanks Abel :) two weeks to go...

Comment: very nice, @JimmyK4542.  yes, I think I got it now.  is the implication b) implies a) just obvious then?  by assuming b) and writing out the matrix, it looks like n-1 columns are just a scalar multiple of the one linearly independent column, with weights given by $y_1^*$, ...$y_n^*$ ...so therefore the matrix A has rank 1.

Comment: Actually, I got it now.  Thanks @JimmyK4542 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you find $b \implies a$ clear, so $a \implies b$ is what we need to prove

There are a few approaches to this problem.

**Option 1:** use the SVD.

Let $A$ be a rank-1 square matrix of size $n$.  We can write 
$$
A = U\Sigma V^*
$$
Let $u_1,\dots,u_n$ denote the columns of $U$ and $v_1,\dots, v_n$ the columns of $V$.  We can write
$$
A = \pmatrix{u_1 & \cdots & u_n} \pmatrix{\sigma_1\\&0\\&&\ddots\\&&&0}
\pmatrix{v_1^* \\ \vdots \\ v_n^*}
$$
computing this product by block-matrix multiplication yields
$$
A = \sigma_1 u_1 v_1^*
$$

In fact, this is another way of looking at SVD.  In general, a rank $k$ matrix can be written as
$$
A = \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i u_i v_i^*
$$

**Option 2:** See Jimmy K's hint in his comment

Comment: This is awesome - thanks so much, @Omnomnomnom.  I have a quick follow-up question:  I was reading up on the SVD after studying your solution and I notice that both Wikipedia as well as other sources refer to the right singular vectors as vectors from the matrix V...and not from $V^*$  Does this make a difference, e.g., are the rows  of $V^*$ also considered right singular vectors?  If so, then $V_2^*$ , ... , $V_n^*$, rows 2 through n, that correspond to the zero singular values, should span the null space of A - just as columns $V_2$ through $V_n$ of the matrix V span the null space of A.

Comment: Or do I have it wrong, and always refer to the matrix V and *not* $V^*$ when picking out a basis (right singular vectors) for the null space of A, from its SVD?  Thanks...

Comment: (and maybe your summation formula already answers this question...)

Comment: It sounds like Wikipedia is referring to the columns of $V$, which are just (the complex conjugates of) the rows of $V^*$.  So, in this case, $v_2,\dots,v_n$ is an orthonormal basis of the null-space of $A$, since $v_1^* v_i = 0$ for $i = 2,\dots,n$.

Comment: Hmmm...I know that for the orthonormal basis $v_1, ... , v_n$, we have that the inner product $<v_1,v_i>$ = 0 for i=2,...,n and for the orthonormal basis $v_1^*, ... , v_n^*$ we have that the inner product $<v_1^*,v_i^*>$ = 0 for i = 2,...,n.  But, how do we know that $<v_1^*,vi>$ = 0 for i = 2,...,n?  Is this a theorem? That $v_1$ is not only orthogonal to $v_2, ..., v_n$ but also orthogonal to $v_2^*, ...v_n^*$?  Thanks, @Omnomnomnom...

Comment: geometrically in the 2D case, I guess it would be make sense, since the conjugated vectors would just flip across the x-axis.  i'm thinking of the (1,0), (0,i), vectors that span the real-axis and imaginary-axis, respectively.  then the basis vector for the y-axis, conjugated, becomes (0, -i), which is still orthogonal to v_1 = (1,0)...

Comment: Remember: $x^*y = \langle y,x \rangle$

Comment: Ok got it.  Thanks so much, @Omnomnomnom :)